# opening new tab on click in silverlight application fails for more than 1 tab

Tags: silverlight

I have a requirement in silverlight. Whenever i click on the grid row, its details should open in new tab. I have implemented the same, but the problem comes when I click a particular link continuously.In that case i get debug error. If I give some time between the clicks like 1-2 secs, then i can open as many tabs i want.

I have used the following code :

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(URI, "_blank");
```

Using this whole application starts again.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: what you expect to get on new page? Just html or new silverlight  app with opened details ?

Comment: A silverlight page again. And it has been implemented. Only thing is when i open too many windows in too short a time, then i get an error.

Comment: actually it's possible, silverlight is a bit heavy itself, so opening dozens windows may get browser stuck. why not just a popup with details? or show them on the same page? using for example silverlight navigation framework?

Comment: the browser does not gets stucked. Only thing is i get debug error as service not working.

Comment: what you mean "service"?

Comment: Web service it is. And the thing is if i open it slowly, i never encounter such error even if i open 15 tabs.

Comment: need to see detailed error what stack trace tells?. maybe really problem is on server, like multithreading/etc

Comment: as a workaround i have called Thread.sleep method..it adds a delay so its not failing anymore with that